# WPF application failing on Azure DevOps build - The runtime pack for Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Runtime.win-x64 was not downloaded

Tags: wpf, azure, azure-devops, yaml

I am trying to set up a build on an Azure DevOps server but my build is failing with the following message
`C:\TFS_bldagent\_work\_tool\dotnet\sdk\3.1.301\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets(317,5): Error NETSDK1112: The runtime pack for Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Runtime.win-x64 was not downloaded. Try running a NuGet restore with the RuntimeIdentifier 'win-x64'.`

In the yaml file I have added a script to run nuget restore with the identifier 'winx-x64' and the yaml file looks like this :

```
variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'


steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@0

- task: UseDotNet@2
  inputs:
    version: '5.0.x'
    includePreviewVersions: true # Required for preview versions

- task: UseDotNet@2 
  inputs:
    version: '3.0.x'
    packageType: runtime

- script: :dotnet restore -r 'win-x64'

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    
    restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    nugetConfigPath: 'nuget.config'
    
    
- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

Has anyone had a similar issue before?

I am using one package in my solution that is not compatible with .net core and is restored using .net framework at the beginning, but I don't think this is causing the issue. The target framework of the app is `netcoreapp3.1`

Comment: Did you try to build the .NET Core app using the `DotNetCoreCLI@2` task?

Comment: Try to add `<RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>` to your project to match what project.json required

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT Yes, I have managed to fix this issue. I used mm8's answer and used the `DotNetCoreCLI@2` task with a `build` command and specified the path to the .csproj file in the `projects` attribute. Your suggestion did not fix the issue, but thank you for the answer!

Comment: @jinx .... can you share more like screenshot where did you add it and how ?